# Does a high Variance imply that outliers are more likely?

Tags: probability, variance, outliers

Does a high Variance with $Var(X)= E(X-\mu)^2$ imply that outliers are more likely?

Comment: How do you define an outlier?

Comment: Values outside $Q_0.25 - 1.5 * IQR$ and $Q_0.75 + 1.5 * IQR$

Comment: How do you even define "high"??

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. When you posted on SE, you gave up 
ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). If there are 
no answers, you may delete your own question (see 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)
): just click the faint gray 'delete' at lower left (your account needs to be 
registered for this). Otherwise, the thread will remain according to SE's rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define an outlier as a point that is more then $1.5 IQR$ above the $75$th or below the $25$th quartiles, then variance does not come into play. As you rescale your distribution, the quartiles are adjusted accordingly. You can see this in a simulation in R.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 10000
x <- rt(N, 1) + 5
y <- x * 77
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(x)
boxplot(y)
par(mfrow=c(1,1)) # set it back to normal
```

Comment: As Andrew Gelman notes, however, outlier detection is a bit dubious: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/06/02/hate-stepwise-regression/.

Comment: Is this chain of thought fair to say ? "One extreme outlier can cause a huge variance, but does not make them more probable, extreme values more likely "

Comment: If I get an extreme point, my instinct is to suspect that the distribution has heavy tails and thus *does* produce "outliers", but I would gather that from visual inspection or inspection of a value called kurtosis (related to the fourth moment).

Comment: Variance is nevertheless implicated because the IQR establishes a lower bound on the variance.

Answer (score 3):

Not always. Consider $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ which implies $10Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,100)$. The distribution of $Z,10Z$ has the exact same shape (just rescaled) and therefore you can think of $Z$ and $10Z$ as having the same behaviour with respect to producing outliers for any random sample, even though the variance of one is greater than the other.